# Will Diskpart Clean All reduce HDD lifespan?

Tags: hard-drive, performance, formatting, hardware-raid

I am planning to reinstall Windows on my PC and I just want everything to be as fresh and new like when it is first used. I thought about doing a Clean All on my hard disk, but I have one question:

Will doing a Clean All greatly reduce my hard disk's lifespan and slow down its speed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What leads you to think that Clean All might have these negative effects?

Comment: By the fact that it will actually damage SSDs.

Comment: and I think that Clean All would require HDDs to spin a lot more times unnecessarily, thereby reducing their lifespans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HDDs are designed to spin and don't generally fail because the bearings wear out.  The activity of Clean All is below the level of noise in terms of potential effect on lifespan.  Flash memory has a limited number of write cycles so activity like Clean All can eat into its lifespan.